# VBA Excel - mso constant is empty

Tags: excel, vba, constants

For some reason I can not get built in mso contants to work.  I have a new installation of Excel 2003 and I ma wondering if I need to include some type of library for it to function any help is appreciated.  Here is an example:

this works:

```
  If sh.Type = 13 Then  ' image found msoPicture
    picIdx = sh.ZOrderPosition ' image index
  End If
```

this doesn't, msoPicure shows as an empty variable

```
  If sh.Type = msoPicture Then  ' image found 
    picIdx = sh.ZOrderPosition ' image index
  End If
```

Next

however, when I look inside `sh` object type correctly shows `msoPicture`

I am baffled and no amount of Google got me anywhere

Comment: Does it compile? Do you have `Option Explicit` stated?

Comment: yes, this program used to run on a different computer

Comment: Just because vba runs doesn't mean when you hit compile it will be a success. Because VBA can be interpreted you can get away with compile errors until you hit them.

Answer (score 1):

`msoPicture` is part of the `Microsoft Office X.Y Object Library`. You need to ensure you have that added as a reference.

[image]

Things you can do to check this out:

- search in Object Browser. If you get no hits, it's not available
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to see if intellisense will see your object
- *Always* have `Option Explicit` set for all the code you write (`Tools > Options > Editor > Require Variable Declaration`)
- Compile often. I like to have the compile button readily available. You can add it you to your toolbar easily `Right click on the toolbar > Customize >  Commands > Debug > Compile Project` (drag it to a good place on your tool bar)

Comment: @TimWilliams I agree. It should be. Is that enum in another library? Is there a conflict you think? Maybe OP unchecked it by accident...

Comment: It's in the library you noted - but it would only be missing if it had been unchecked.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I knew it had to do with references but did not know which one.   It doesn't look like I have generic MS office Object library instead I have specific apps MS Objects.

Comment: @user3512822, like TimWilliams says, unless you have unchecked that reference it should be included by default.

Comment: this is what my choices are that are unchecked [image] (http://i.imgur.com/H9h4A6z.png?1)

Comment: @user3512822, and what IS checked at the top of the dialog?

Comment: I found it.   And it was unchecked.  The problem was that the reference list looks like it is sorted but in reality it is not.  Microsoft Office library is close to the top a few rows down.